# Migrating from Jasmine 1.3 to Jasmine 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I have some JavaScript that I'm testing with Jasmine. I want to run the tests in the browser window when a user presses "run tests". With Jasmine 1.3, I have successfully set that up as shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YQDWY/) with this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jasmineEnv.execute()">run tests</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jasmineEnv = (function () {
        var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
        jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

        var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
        jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);

        jasmineEnv.specFilter = function (spec) {
            return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
        };
        return jasmineEnv;
    })();
</script>
```

Jasmine 2.0 offers some new capabilities that I really need. However, I cannot figure out how to get it setup such that the tests run when someone clicks a "run tests" button. I'm using the new boot.js file. However, I'm not having any luck. Can someone please help me migrate that sample from Jasmine 1.3 to Jasmine 2.0?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test cases execution is triggered by below snipped in file `boot.js`:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    if (currentWindowOnload) {
      currentWindowOnload();
    }
    htmlReporter.initialize();
    env.execute();
  };
```

Either you can modify this implementation in `boot.js` file itself to execute under a function call or you can write your custom boot code inspired from actual `boot.js`.

Comment: Would you mind updating the jsfiddle to show the whole code? My fork of it (http://jsfiddle.net/YQDWY/1/) is still problematic :(

Comment: Pat, i am little occupied this week, but definitely i will upload it by next week.

Comment: @Pat - The jsFiddle what you have shared is having jasmine 1.3 version. Are you looking for solving it on 1.3 or 2.0? Because the actual question is "working in 1.3, what is the option for 2.0".

Comment: I cloned that fiddle from the OP's fiddle, so I didn't even check the jasmine version. I'm interested in jasmine 2 as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, as per the actual question, it was working for 1.3 version, but the user was facing problem with 2.0 version. Did you try implementing in 2.0?

Comment: I didn't try in 2.0, no. Locally, I have 2.0 but couldn't get it to work. So I wanted to see if a simple example would work in jsfiddle, but I didn't try uploading the v2.0 files (because I didn't notice that they were v1.3). But I gave up and went with mocha :)

Answer (score 1):

*Can't post this as a comment yet!*

Jasmine 2.0 in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/88Xa6/4/ 
As mentioned by @user3037143 initialization is handled at boot.js.

Ensure the library files are in place:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css">

<!-- Add any custom reporters (Console / Junit / etc) here. 
     Ensure necessary initialization triggers are set in 
     boot when adding more reporters. -->
<script type='text/javascript' src="/libs/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
```

You can either choose to include the spec or have them defined inline:

```
<script src="spec.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    describe("My Suite", function() {
        it("Should be true", function() {
            expect(1).toBe(1);
        });
    });
</script>
```